# How to determine whether a checkbox is checked or not in Vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I just want to determine whether a checkbox is checked or not in Vue js 2. In jquery we have functions like **$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');** which will return true if checkbox is checked or not. What is the equivalent function in Vue js.

Here is the scenario with code. Please note i am using laravel with its blade templates.

```
@foreach ($roles as $role)
   <input type="checkbox" v-on:click="samplefunction({{$role->id}})" v-model="rolesSelected" value="{{$role->id}}">                       
@endforeach
```

The js part is

```
<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app1',
    data: {
      rolesSelected:"",
    },
    methods : {
      samplefunction : function(value) {
        // Here i want to determine whether this checkbox is checked or not   
      }
    },
  });

</script>
```

Comment: You'd bind the checkbox to a variable then listen to the variable. `rolesSelected ` could be multidimensional.

Comment: Follow this documentation https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox, it has a good example

Comment: @admcfajn rolesSelected is not multidimentional.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra I referred every vuejs official documentation and did not find any. That is why i asked.

Comment: @GeordyJames maybe use radio instead of checkboxes? That'll make it so only one can be selected at a time.

Comment: @admcfajn I cannot use radio buttons since i need checkboxes for doing some other tasks in server side.

Comment: @GeordyJames I think I see what you mean. I'd work around it using the `ref` attribute on the checkbox. That'll give you access to the element itself. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref and use native-js' `.checked`

Comment: I don't understand but what's the difference between your use case with the first example in the official document Dharma mentioned.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
if(this.rolesSelected != "") {
   alert('isSelected');
}
```

or
`v-on:click="samplefunction({{$role->id}},$event)"`

```
samplefunction : function(value,event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
       alert('isSelected');
    }
}
```

Comment: I spent some time to figure out how checkbox work. It different with input text type. First use `v-on:click` not `v-on:input` and use `event.target.checked` not `event.target.value`.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me.

```
<input type="checkbox" :id="poid" class="unchecked" name="single_select" ref="rolesSelected">

function (){
  if(this.$refs.rolesSelected.checked == false) {
    //do something
  }
}

function (){
  if(this.$refs.rolesSelected.checked == true) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the event handler `change` instead of `click` and add a second argument `$event` into your function call like:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-on:change="samplefunction({{$role->id}}, $event)" v-model="rolesSelected" value="{{$role->id}}">
```

In your methods, use the second argument and check with `event.target.checked` if your checkbox is `true` or `false`, clicked or not clicked

```
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app1',
    data: {
      rolesSelected:"",
    },
    methods : {
      samplefunction : function(value, event) {
        if(event.target.checked) {
          console.log('The checkbox is clicked')
        }   
      }
    },
  });
```